# vundle: ConqueTerm: not an edit command

Tags: vim, plugins

I tried to install `Conque-Shell` via Vundle, and when I input `:ConqueTerm bash` in vim, it showed `'ConqueTerm: Not an edit command'`. I thought there was something wrong with my path. But I did write `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle` in my .gvimrc. And the configure of Vundle is at the beginning of the `.gvimrc`.

I copied the `.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/plugin/conque_term.vim` to `.vim/plugin/conque_term.vim` and then it worked.

So, is there anything wrong with my `.gvimrc`?? Thanks!

My `.gvimrc`: https://gist.github.com/guori12321/5506991

Comment: Don't do that in `~/.gvimrc`, do that in `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the output of `:scriptnames` (the list of scripts sourced during startup), you'll note that `.gvimrc` comes last, after `.vimrc` and the plugins. Therefore, any changes to the `'runtimepath'` there are too late; plugins (like *ConqueTerm*) have already been loaded. You can read more about the startup process at `:help initialization`.

Even if you only use the GUI GVIM, put the common settings into `~/.vimrc`; the `~/.gvimrc` file is for GUI-only stuff that doesn't apply to the terminal Vim, e.g. setting `'guifont'` and similar options.